# Can you use Selenium with a phonegap application?

Tags: cordova, selenium

We need to know if is it possible to use selenium with a phonegap app. 
We are trying sikuli for automation but we prefer selenium if it would be possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *it depends* answer leaning towards no.

If you are loading the HTML from the SD Card then no. Apps can't access the assets from another app as far as I know because that can create IP/Copyright nightmares.

If your app is hosted on a site and then loaded the app then some of it can be tested. The parts that interact with Cordova won't be able to be tested.