# How to debug GUI part in Phonegap application?

Tags: android, unit-testing, user-interface, cordova, qunit

I am writing a very simple Phonegap application on android.  The problem is how to automatically test the GUI part of it. QUnit looks like a good choice to test only Javascript but it needs jquery library to support testing user actions, according to the [Cookbook](http://qunitjs.com/cookbook/). Is it appropriate to include JQuery library in Phonegap application for testing purpose?

Here is an simple scenario. I have an input field in the application. And I want to test it to see if it could accept value. How should I do with it in Phonegap? Or is there other choice to test the GUI part of Phonegap application?

I also found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934125/automated-testing-of-phonegap-cordova-apps) about Selenium but I am trying to find other possible ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova (formerly Phonegap), by itself (basically), nothing have to do with javascript, it just a tool to wrap your html/js/css code in android WebView element. Cordova has methods to access device internals via cordova provided JS calls.

Well, you can unit-test your application even in chrome desktop browser. Also, if you want, you can include any JS libraries to be used in App. If you have any questions- just write comment

Comment: Do you mean that you can test the app (this simple test case) with Selenium?

Comment: I have not used Selenium nor know his capabilities so I can not confirm. But I guess  answer is positive. App itself is web-based application that works in browser